# SPI connection to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, current-limiting

I want to flash and configure a processor using a Raspberry Pi. For this I'm using the SPI pins of the Raspberry Pi.

I read that the Raspberry Pi pins can provide no more than 8 mA out of each pin. Do I need to limit the current on the SPI pins with a series resistor?

Or can I just connect them directly to the SPI pins of the processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify which controller you want to interface to the RPi.
But a typical SPI peripheral won't sink a lot of current; 8mA would be more than enough.

I wouldn't recommend adding series resistors. They'll negatively affect the signal edges and thus reduce the maximum bitrate.

Just connect the signals directly:

- SCLK -> SCLK
- MOSI -> MOSI
- MISO <- MISO
- #SS -> #SS

Answer (score 1):

Don't limit the current, that will only slow the rise/fall time of your clock and data lines.

SPI is normally a direct connection from master to slave.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, in this case, is not the current but the voltage level. If the processor operates at 3.3V, you can connect it directly, and if the processor works at 5V, you have to use resistors or a level converter for the MISO pin.

Comment: The processor operates at 3.3V, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Pololu USB AVR Programmer v2.1 with Raspberry Pi to program ATmega328P devices using AVRdude:

https://www.pololu.com/product/3172

This solution works with the USB port on the RPI. Although your application is different it might be helpful to study the user manual for this product or similar product with open source documentation.